# Why is the total incorrect?

Tags: php, drupal-6, ubercart

I am looking on page: admin/store/orders/46474

```
Subtotal:   $19.89
FedEx Home Delivery:    $17.52
Coupon: CF30:   -$5.97
Subtotal excluding taxes:   $31.44
NY Tax: $1.04
Total:  $32.49
```

When I add up the items myself, I get 32.48 for the total. Where can I go to fix this error?

Comment: The float is the problem. Always round up the final price so that you don't loose some cents on each order.

Comment: Where do I go to do that? That's my question.